If a system is found to be in a degenerate energy level, which specific eigenstate is it in and at what probability?
Let's say we measure a system's energy and find that it is in a degenerate energy level. Which specific eigenstate of that eigenenergy should we find it in? My first thought was that, since we did not split the degeneracy, it's like we didn't measure it at all, so there's no way to know. Moreover, any linear combination of degenerate eigenstates is an eigenstate, so we cannot just consider it in superposition of eigenstates and call it a day.
But actually, we can still measure the eigenstates in the degenerate state. Let's say we are in the ground state of the ferromagnetic Ising model, and we measure the spin of one site on some $S_z$ axis. After a million measurements, we should encounter some distribution of the two eigenstates in that axis! And it could have been 30/70, 50/50, etc. since they all are eigenstates too!
So from this Wikipedia article, I found this quote:

These degenerate states at the same level all have an equal probability of being filled. The number of such states gives the degeneracy of a particular energy level.

If 50/50 is the case according to the quote, I was wondering, what is the justification for this? And is the system in a quantum superposition state, or is it more like a classical mixture of eigenstates? Thank you!

See Lüders' rule.

I'm sorry, but could you clarify it? From what I understand, it's similar to the answer by Lukas below, stating that the wave function collapses to the eigenspace, but it states nothing about the specific distribution of those eigenstates and why is it so (even though this distribution certainly exists, as we can just do another measurement). My question is what is the state of the system in-between the two measurements (let's say 1st energy and 2nd in spin basis), when the system is in that eigenspace; what is its state/distribution in the basis of the second measurement?

@Juan That Wikipedia quote is somewhat misleading, but look at the context of that paragraph: they're talking about the case of statistical mechanics, in which the states are equally likely to be classically occupied, since the Boltzmann factor depends only on the energy of the state and not on any other quantum numbers. But in zero-temperature quantum mechanics, the state of the system can certainly be any linear combination of these degenerate states; the mixture doesn't have to be equal probabilities.

For simplicity, let's assume that the sectrum of $\hat H$ is discrete (otherwise it wouldn't be possible to realise an ideal measurement of $\hat H$
Let the energy eigen basis of the system is given by $\vert \lambda\rangle_{\lambda}$ with corresponding eigenvalues
$$
\hat H |\lambda \rangle = E_\lambda |\lambda \rangle\,.
$$
Now suppose that you "measure" the value $\tilde E$ and there are exactly two values $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that $E_{\lambda_1} = E_{\lambda_2} = \tilde E$. If the state prior to the measurement was given by
$$
|\psi_i\rangle = \sum_{\lambda} \alpha_\lambda |\lambda\rangle\,
$$
then according to the projection postulate the state after a the measurement of $\hat H = \tilde E$ would be given (up to normalization) by the orthogonal projection to the eigenspace of $\tilde E$. I.e.,
$$
|\psi_f\rangle = \mathcal N \cdot ( |\lambda_1\rangle \langle \lambda_1| + |\lambda_2 \rangle \langle \lambda_2|)\sum_{\lambda} \alpha_\lambda |\lambda\rangle
= \mathcal N (\alpha_{\lambda_1} |\lambda_1\rangle + \alpha_{\lambda_2} |\lambda_2\rangle)\,.
$$

Yes I see, but this doesn't seem to answer the question. Obviously I don't know the state prior to measurement, so I don't know those $\alpha_{\lambda}$. Measuring to $\tilde{E}$ would collapse to the subspace of the degenerate states, so I now know $\alpha_{\lambda} = 0 \ \forall \lambda \neq 1,2$, but still I don't know the distribution for $1,2$ or whether it's 50/50. Am I correct in saying that?

Yes you are correct. The measurement neither yields  information about the coefficients, nore does it change the ration $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}$. I.e. the distribution is not measured. However, the $\alpha_{\lambda_i}$s could be determined by a subsequence measurement, e.g., of the spin operator.

I think the problem is that this ratio is totally arbitrary. For the same Hamiltonian, it could be 50/50, 70/30, etc. and according to Wikipedia, it's 50/50. If true, why is that the case and if not, what's the actual state of the system here?

@Juan "I think the problem is that this ratio is totally arbitrary." Why do you say that? That ratio is determined by the pre-measurement state, because the post-measurement state is the projection of the pre-measurement state onto the relevant eigenspace. That is the state of the system after the measurement! It's some superposition of the degenerate states, that superposition being determined by the pre-measurement state. It seems like there's some disconnect/misconception in your thinking here, but it's hard to figure out exactly what it is. Can you clarify?

@Juan "For the same Hamiltonian, it could be 50/50, 70/30, etc. and according to Wikipedia, it's 50/50." This is part of the misconception: the Hamiltonian doesn't determine the state of the system; rather, it determines a privileged basis for the space of quantum state of the system. The actual state is determined by whatever state-preparation procedure was used to prepare the state, which can be written as a linear combination of the energy eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (the privileged basis I mention above).

But wouldn't that mean the physics of a Hamiltonian is highly sensitive to the initial state, which seems like something that would break the assumption of statistical mechanics?

@Juan. No; you just have some misconception that I can't quite figure out. The Hamiltonian determines the equation of motion for the state of the system, but it in no way determines the actual state of the system (other than specifying the total space of possible states). Conversely, the Hamiltonian describes the system irrespective of what state the system is. The initial state is just whatever the experimenter chooses to prepare (equivalently, whatever the theorist decided she is investigating). I'd like to drill down on this and figure out where your confusion is!

Thank you for helping me! I think my main confusion is whether the degeneracy is of classical or quantum nature. So I understand that if we have a system evolving to some Hamiltonian, and we let it interact with a reservoir (canonical ensemble), it will thermalize following the Boltzmann distribution. This degeneracy is to me of classical nature. But let's say we prepare an initial state, and let it evolve solely with that Hamiltonian without a reservoir (microcanonical), and then measure to find it in a degenerate level, would the state end up in a quantum superposition? Is this the answer?

I guess, this would depend on the context. Firstly, if you consider an isolated system without heat bath, the mixture will be preserved over time since the time evolution is given by
$$ \alpha_{\lambda_1} |\lambda_1\rangle +\alpha_{\lambda_2}|\lambda_2\rangle \mapsto e^{-i t \tilde E/\hbar}\alpha_{\lambda_1}  |\lambda_1\rangle +\alpha_{\lambda_2}|\lambda_2\rangle$$. If you interact with some enviroment, $H = H_\text{Sys} + H_\text{Int} + H_\text{bath}$ it would depend on the interaction $H_\text{Int}$. If it is symmetric in $|\lambda_i\rangle$ it should lead to 50/50 mixture.

I'll give the non-abstract look, maybe even an answer. So as an example I think about boron, the 1st atom (ordered by $Z$) to get a P-shell electron.
For physicists, that has 3 degenerate angular states (ignoring spin):
$$ \Big(Y_1^{-1}(\theta, \phi), Y_1^{0}(\theta, \phi), Y_1^{+1}(\theta, \phi)\Big)$$
So it can be in a coherent mixture of any of them, which is different super position for a different choice of a z-axis.
You can also look at the chemist's version of P-orbits, which are the linear combinations that look like:
$$ \Big(\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta\Big) $$
aka:
$$ \Big(x, y, z \Big)$$
The point is: atoms don't care about our choice of coordinates, so it can't pick a state to be in.
Whether it's in an unknown pure state, or the maximum entropy distribution:
$$ \rho \propto 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
where the choice of basis doesn't matter, because the density matrix is the same in any orthogonal basis, is a matter of choice in describing the problem. So I say: it's up to you.
If ignoring the spins and multi-electron state bothers you, then apply the same reasoning to a single electron spin state: any pure mixture of $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$ is a pure spin up state in another coordinate system, and the electron doesn't know about our choice of coordinates.
That is the nature of essential degeneracy: the problem has spherical symmetry, so the labels of the degenerate states depend on our choice of coordinates, and the physical state cannot.
I'm not going to address accidental degeneracy, for example the $l$-quantum number degeneracy in Coulomb atoms. There the states are physically different. I would need to think about it more.
